# Roblox if value change print 1 else print 2

Tags: lua, roblox

I don't really know how to do it, so all I could find is something like this for example:

```lua
Local abc = script.parent

abc.Changed:Connect(function()
Print(“1”)

end)
Else 
Print(“2”)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to store the old value and then check when you need to do if the value is changed and print accordingly. Here's an example.

```lua
local abc = script.Parent.Value

--- When you need to check if it's changed

if script.Parent.Value ~= abc then
    print("Changed")
else
    print("Same")
end
```